# RxJS: Why is 'this' undefined within subscribe

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to setup a simple error notifications component, whilst debugging in Visual Studio, within subscribe, **this** appears to be undefined.

```
public notifications: NotificationMessage[]; 

constructor(notificationService: NotificationService) {
    this.notifications = []; //'this' is defined here

    notificationService.rxEmitter.subscribe((notificationMessages: any) => {
        this.notifications = notificationMessages; //'this' is undefined here
    });
}
```

Edit : [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoqfY.png) of this being undefined from a breakpoint in VS. Interestingly, '_this', *does* exist at runtime, though I can't reference it as typescript throws an reference not found error on compilation.

Comment: This is very unlikely. Arrow functions don't work like that. Either real code differs from the one you've posted, or you have an error somewhere else. Consider providing http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the issue, a plunk would be fine.

Comment: have you tried to put the subscribe call in an ngOnInit method? it seems like it's called before your constructor actually created the object, so this is undefined at this time.

Comment: @Supamiu shouldnt be the case, op should provide a plnkr as the code seems fine to me

Comment: @Supamiu can confirm using ngOnInit didn't fix this, 'this' remains undefined. I'll try to set up a plnkr..

Comment: So unfortunately creating a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TTpBvKZ2QO6P1azRRd9L) doesn't recreate the issue.  There is another error, but this is defined. It must be an issue with my environment in visual studio.

Comment: @Supamiu Huh? Of course `this` is defined in the constructor.

Comment: How do you know, or why do you think, that `this` is undefined (which as others have said, is impossible)? PS. `EventEmitters` should not be used as observables. Even if it works now, it might not work in the future. `EventEmitter` is meant for component outputs.

Comment: Did you ever have a function instead of an arrow function? If you did it could be that the typescript code has not yet successfully transpiled after you made the change to arrow function (possibly due to a bug in another script or in the same script). Delete the output-ed `.js` file and see if the typescript file is re-transpiled.

Comment: @torazaburo As I set a breakpoint, setting a watch on this says that the second 'this' is undefined when it executes, I've attached an image in an edit.

Comment: @Igor thanks for the tip, but deleting the js files didn't solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Visual Studios debugger was giving me a red herring saying this is undefined. Testing it out with console.log gave a valid output.

Visual Studio has trouble with arrow functions. Typescript compiles **this** to **_this**.

[image: compiled js of NotifierComponent]

If you create a breakpoint from within subscribe and inspect **this**, Visual Studios debugger will be inspecting the anonymous function in the generated javascript code above and can no longer find  **this**.

A workaround is to inspect **_this** instead.

This article seems to describe my issue.

https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1655